# Converting a string into something else

Tags: string, powershell, size, powershell-2.0

my script is now nearly finished. I use it to find big folders / subfolders etc..
i did not understand the format parameter -f yet, even though i checked the examples 3 times or even more :).

right now my script orders the sizes by strings. so  15 mb is smaller than 2 mb.

i have around  300 folders to check and it's better to convert that string to a number.

Thank you in advance!

here is my the part of my script which does this :

```
    function Folders-Size($folders)
{
    $directories = @()
    foreach ($i in $folders)
    {
        $childItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $size = "{0:N2}" -f ($childItems.sum / 1MB)
        $name = $i.FullName
        $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name=$name; Size=$size}
        $directories += $data
    }    
    $directories = $directories | Sort-Object Size -descending
    $directories

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$directories | Sort-Object { [decimal]::parse($_.Size) } -descending
```

Comment: i use this script on my local machine and i have 4 folders here with the sizes : 1,5 gb , 10mb , 0,01 mb and 0mb. Now it shows them in this Order : 10,00 MB , 0,09 MB, 0,00Mb and last 1.572,67 MB    and without -descending  it's the opposite. something is not working correctly.

Comment: @RayofCommand I've edited my answer, did you use edited version?

Comment: @RayofCommand Glad to help! In first version I've missed your `/ 1MB` to convert value, then casting to [int] returns wrong order!